# How can you get a user's IP in PlayFramework2 ?

Tags: nginx, playframework-2.0

For security reasons, sometimes it is needed to block users by IP. In my case, I would like to manage the IP blacklist in a (SQL) database. I guess I can handle the filter part based on Action Composition but for that I need the user's IP.

**So, how can I get the user's IP?**

PS : The application is running behind a nginx proxy.

Comment: (1) Where is your research effort? (2) Have you setup in nginx something like `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header for your Play! backend?

Comment: I found a post about it on the ML but it was about Play 1.x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's now possible with Play **2.0.2+** : [RequestHeader.remoteAddress()](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestHeader.html#remoteAddress%28%29)

Java :

```
String ip = request().remoteAddress();
```

Scala :

```
Action { request =>
    val ip = request.remoteAddress()
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Still haven't tried it. Maybe this evening if I have some time!

Comment: Doesn't work. Using Play 2.5.10, I'm getting 0:0:0:0:0:0:0.

Answer (score 9):

If your Play! app is behind nginx (or any other reverse proxy), `request.remoteAddress()` will only return the IP address of your nginx host. In order to retrieve the real IP of the client you should have the following in your proxy_pass configuration of nginx:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass        http://play-app:9000;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
}
```

This will add the client IP as parameter to the header

doc: [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule)

And then within your Play! app you would retrieve it like this:

```
request.headers.get("X-Real-IP") //In Java
request.headers.get("X-Real-IP") //In Scala
```

doc: [Java](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestHeader.html#headers%28%29), [Scala](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request)

Comment: I set header as `X-Real-IP` in nginx but can only get value from `x-real-ip`, don't know why.

Comment: what happens when using apache ?