# Find IP address in a playframework application

Tags: java, playframework, location, playframework-2.0, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you get a user's IP in PlayFramework2 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207654/how-can-you-get-a-users-ip-in-playframework2)

I have a play framework application in which the user enters a form submits it, and `routes` have been setup to display the post via `index.scala.html` file.

How can I get the user's IP address ? I would like to tag that post with his location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a controller :

```
request.remoteAddress;
```

Outside a controller :

```
Http.Request.current.get().remoteAddress;
```